# Array 'map' vs 'forEach' - functional programming

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functional-programming

I have an array of objects:

```
let reports = [{ inbound_calls: [...], outbound_calls: [...],  outbound_national_calls: [...] },...];
```

What is the best way to create a new array and assign into a variable:

**1st approach - one loop:**

```
let inbound_calls = []; outbound_national_calls = [], outbound_calls = [];

reports.forEach((e) => {
 inbound_calls.push(e.inbound_calls);
 outbound_national_calls.push(e.outbound_national_calls);
 outbound_calls.push(e.outbound_calls);
})
```

**2nd approach:**

```
let inbound_calls = this.reports.map((report) => report.inbound_calls)
let outbound_national_calls = this.reports.map((report) => report.outbound_national_calls)
let outbound_calls = this.reports.map((report) => report.outbound_calls)
```

I'm starting to learn functional programming, and want to apply it to my code, I would go with first approach (one loop), but as I did research about functional programming I think the second one is the right way (much cleaner) but, I'm not sure, what is less expensive operation?

Comment: The `forEach()` loop will be the _less expensive_ operation. If performance is an absolute necessity, the traditional `for()` loop is the fastest loop in the JS runtime.

Comment: @MátéSafranka yeah. Technically, with this code, the easiest thing would be to do `inbound_calls = reports.inboundCalls.slice()`. However, I think the question still has merit, probably it would make more sense if `reports` contains something like `[ { inbound_calls: ...} ]`

Answer (score 3):

If your ultimate goal is to create three variables out of the object, you may use object destructuring as follows. No loops required.

```js
let reports = {
  inbound_calls: [1, 2, 3],
  outbound_calls: [4, 5, 6],
  outbound_national_calls: [7, 8, 9]
};

let {inbound_calls, outbound_calls, outbound_national_calls} = reports;
console.log(inbound_calls);
console.log(outbound_calls);
console.log(outbound_national_calls);
```

Comment: And the least expensive operation yet! Nice answer.

Comment: Note that this doesn't copy the arrays. Any mutation to the variables will also mutate the original arrays.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir -- What OP has coded, does the same thing. OP didn't mention anywhere that he wants to create a copy. Still, if the copy is needed, using `slice` is obviously preferred.

Comment: @31piy No, it doesn't. OP's code is wrong anyway. Also OP is clearly intending to copy the items. Not sure if that is really what he wants but sure not what his code is aiming for.

Comment: Thanks for that but I had mistake in my question reports is array, so I can't use destruction like this there...

Comment: @Klark -- in that case, I would say, the second snippet is more of a functional approach, but the first one is more optimal. And, still, you're not copying the array's elements. If those are objects, modifications done in one will change the originals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the arrays, just use `Array#slice` (the `0` passed is optional as it is the default start index so you can omit it if you want) like:

```
let inbound_calls = reports.inbound_calls.slice(0),
    outbound_national_calls = reports.outbound_national_calls.slice(0), 
    outbound_calls = reports.outbound_calls.slice(0);
```

or `Array.from` like:

```
let inbound_calls = Array.from(reports.inbound_calls),
    outbound_national_calls = Array.from(reports.outbound_national_calls), 
    outbound_calls = Array.from(reports.outbound_calls);
```

Comment: You don't need to supply `0` to `.slice()` - that's the default value. Calling it without an argument is enough.

Comment: @vlaz Right. I've added a note regarding it. I still think providing it is better as it is much clearer.

Comment: I can see your point. I did actually use to do that but at some point I stopped. I can definitely see merits for either way of calling this. In the beginning I did it because something else required a start parameter and it was less confusing to me to always supply it to `.slice()`. Later on, I came back to JS after doing something else and I actually forgot to add the index for a while until I came across some older code. It's not a big deal either way, so as long as you're consistent, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you're essentially doing is a matrix transposition:

```js
const report = (inbound_calls, outbound_calls, outbound_national_calls) =>
    ({ inbound_calls, outbound_calls, outbound_national_calls });

const reports = [report(1,2,3), report(4,5,6), report(7,8,9)];

const transpose = reports =>
    report( reports.map(report => report.inbound_calls)
          , reports.map(report => report.outbound_calls)
          , reports.map(report => report.outbound_national_calls) );

console.log(transpose(reports));
```

Now, depending upon your application the fastest way to transpose a matrix might be not to transpose it at all. For example, suppose you have a matrix `A` and its transpose `B`. Then, it holds that for all indices `i` and `j`, `A[i][j] = B[j][i]`. Consider:

```js
const report = (inbound_calls, outbound_calls, outbound_national_calls) =>
    ({ inbound_calls, outbound_calls, outbound_national_calls });

const reports = [report(1,2,3), report(4,5,6), report(7,8,9)];

// This is equivalent to transpose(reports).outbound_calls[1]
const result = reports[1].outbound_calls;

console.log(result);
```

That being said, your second approach is IMHO the most readable.